# Access controls that were created at run time

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

In my form i have a "plus-button", when the user click on it a new `TextBox` is added to the form:

```
private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.Name = "textBox" + countTb.ToString();
    this.Controls.Add(tb);
    countTb++;
}
```

My problem is: I don't know how to access these `TextBoxes`.
I have a save-button, when user clicks it i have to save all `TextBox.Text` into database, but I don't know how to find them.

Comment: add it to a `List<TextBox>` also, then later iterate through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Controls.OfType` if the `TextBoxes` are on top of the form:

```
var allTextBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
foreach(TextBox txt in allTextBoxes)
{
    // ...
}
```

Another approach is to use [`ControlCollection.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find controls with a given name:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= countTb; i++)
{
    Control[] txtArray = this.Controls.Find("textBox" + i, true); // recursive search
    if (txtArray.Length > 0)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)txtArray[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily save button names on array or you can access to form text boxes from --> this.controls

Answer (score 0):

To get all of the TextBoxes on the form, you can do the following:

```
var textBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
```

Then you can iterate over them all to get their text values:

```
foreach(var textBox in textBoxes)
{
    var text = textBox.Text;
    //do something to save the values.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to access the text box after you have created it would be to insert it into an array or list, this way you would be able to iterate through that list/array to access any number of text boxes and save the data inside to a database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save all `TextBox.Text` values on the form in one comma-delimited string:

```
var allText = string.Join(",", Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Select(x => x.Text));
```

You'll need to clarify your question more, if this won't work.

- This will grab the value of *every* TextBox on the form, so if you don't want to save the values from some, you'll need to filter them out first.
- If you want a list, so you can save one record per TextBox, then remove `string.Join`.